# how to change my Android studio color back to default from black with some auto color adjustments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

i am very confused and unable change the color of my android studio IDE color and how i face very much difficulty to code on this type of settings.

Comment: Reinstall android studio xD Just kidding. Refer to the link posted by Nilesh. You'll get your answer.

Comment: File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts-> In scheme name select theme as per requirement. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it from here

[image]

Then in Settings:

[image]

Comment: thankyou so much exactly that i wants

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File->Settings->Appearance and behavior->Appearance`

Change `theme` to `intellij`